# Behaviour of reference(&) data member pointing to stack variable

Tags: c++, reference, stack, scope

I have come across a sample source code regarding use reference data member and i am confused about output. Here is sample code.

```
class Test {
private:
    int &t;
public:
    Test (int y):t(y) {  }
    int getT() { return t; }
};

int main() {
    int x = 20;
    Test t1(x);
    cout << t1.getT() << "\n"; // Prints 20 as output. however y has already been destroyed but still prints 20.
    x = 30;
    cout << t1.getT() << endl; // Prints Garbage as output Why ? Ideally both steps should be Garbage.
    return 0;
}
```

And to add for more confusion here is one more piece of code for same class

```
int main() {
    int x = 20;
    int z = 60;
    Test t1(x);
    Test t2(z);
    cout<<t1.getT()<<"\n"; // Prints 60! WHY? Should print garbage
    cout<<t2.getT() << "\n"; // Prints Garbage  
    cout<<t1.getT() << endl; // Prints Same Garbage value as previous expression
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i got it. Yes it is undefined but to answer my question why it is printing 20 or 60 before printing garbage? Actually answer is that 20 and 60 both values are garbage and ideally both getT function calls should print Garbage but it doesn't.Because there is no other instruction between `Test t2(z);
    cout<<t1.getT()<<"\n";` 
but for next statement \n works as a instruction and meanwhile stack clears the value.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is passed *by value* using a *temporary*, so `t` is a reference to *that temporary*, not `x`. That temporary will be destroyed after constructor returns. Your code has *undefined behavior*. anything can come up as output. Your problem can be solved by passing a reference to `x` like

```
Test (int& y):t(y);
```

but this is not a good idea. There can be cases where `x` goes out of scope but the `Test` object is still used , then the same problem will appear.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor:

```
Test (int y):t(y) {  }
```

sets t to be a reference to y, the local (temporary) variable on the stack, and not the variable in the calling function.  When you change the variable value in the calling function it does not change anything in the object you created.

The fact that the reference is to a temporary variable that is lost at the end of the life of the constructor means that getT() returns an undefined value.

Every call to `int getT()` accesses the memory address for y.  That memory address was released from the stack at the end of the constructor, so it points to memory that is not on the stack or the heap and so may be reused at any time.  The time of reuse is not defined and depends on other operations established by the compiler and dependency libraries.  The return value of `int getT()` therefor depends on other elements on your OS that affect memory, the compiler type and version, and the OS amongst other things.

Comment: actually i am concerned about the timing when the value is being flushed on memory address of y. In first getT statement it prints the value of the address which has already been destroyed, but still prints some value not a garbage value.

Comment: `getT()` causes undefined behaviour (not just "returns an undefined value") - anything could happen

Comment: I've added a third paragraph with some details about undefined behaviour.  It is worth pointing out that in your example the first getT() appears to work, but it is still undefined - if you ran it 1000 times or ran it on another OS you may get a different result!